# Android: How to get specific data from list view

Tags: android

I created a custom list view and set text on `product_name` and `code`.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_item, null, true);
    TextView txtProduct = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textProduct);
    TextView txtCode = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textCode);

    txtProduct.setText(product_name[position]);
    txtCode.setText(code[position]);

    return listViewItem;
}
```

How can I set `OnItemClickListener` to get each data from the list view and pass to another activity.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Data data=listView.getAdapter().getPosition(arg2);
Intent intent=new Intent(this,newActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Key",data);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: with this i pass both product_name and code or just one. How can I separate it ??

Comment: intent.putExtra("keyForProduct",product_name); intent.putExtra("keyForCode,code);

Answer (score 0):

on your CustomListViewAdapter you should have something like this:

```
private final List<Object> mList;

//public constructor, random name
public MyCustomListViewAdapter(Context c, List<Object> list) {
    context = c;
    this.mList = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mList.get(position).getId();
}
```

When retrieving data from the list, you just call

```
listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

and if will return your Custom Object at the position you're sending.